# How can I use cctrlapp without constantly entering credentials?

Tags: cloudcontrol

I've started playing experimenting with [cloudcontrol.com](http://cloudcontrol.com). They provide a cli application called cctrlapp for managing projects.

However, many useful operations require a login. It is cumbersome and frustrating to have to put in my email address and password every time I push the current state of my app.

Can ccrtlapp be configured to use stored credentials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended: We now support authentication via public-keys between CLI and API which is more secure and more convenient. To set it up, simply run:

```
$ cctrluser setup
```

Read more about this here: http://www.paasfinder.com/introducing-public-key-authentication-for-cli-and-api/

Alternatively: You can set your credentials via the 'CCTRL_EMAIL' and 'CCTRL_PASSWORD' environment variables. If set, they're automatically used by cctrlapp.